# Does HP UFT 12.5 work with Chrome 52?

Tags: automated-testing, qtp, uft

I am using HP UFT version 12.5 and I have Google Chrome version 52.

I'm not sure if it supported by Chrome 52 version or not?

Please help, I am very new to it and kindly provide some tutorial link as well for the same.

Answer (score 1):

QTP/UFT vs Chrome Support Matrix[image]

Hope it helps

Comment: That i have seen before. So it wnt work with HP UFT 12.52?

Answer (score 0):

Iterations for Chrome are so fast these days that it is almost impossible for a company to keep pace with it.
By the time HPE comes up with a support for new version of Chrome; Chrome has already advanced by 2 major versions.

HPE may not be publishing each and every time when a new Chrome versions launches but there are chances your version of UFT would work if it was working for *near* prior versions.

As per [UFT/QTP: Browser Support Matrix for IE, Firefox, Chrome, Netscape & Safari](http://www.learnqtp.com/uft-qtp-browser-support-matrix/), UFT 12.52 supports Chrome v50 with Patch 1. So you may try with the same patch for Chrome v52.